# How does R decide which parameters are inside the intercept for dummy coding?

Tags: r, regression, anova

Let's construct a simple example. Below is the code.

```
A<-gl(2,4) #factor of 2 levels 
B<-gl(4,2) #factor of 4 levels
df<-data.frame(y,A,B)
```

As you can see, B is nested within A. 
The peculiar result I am interested in the output of the model matrix when I fit for a nested model . How does R decide what is included inside the intercept? Since we are using dummy coding, the coefficients of the model is interpreted as the difference between a particular level and the reference level/the intercept for an single factor model. I understand for model ~A, A1 becomes the intercept and that for model ~A+B, A1 and B1 (both) become the intercept.

I do not get why when we use a nested model, A1:B2 appears as a column inside the model matrix. Why isn't the first parameter of the interaction subspace A1:B1 or A2:B1? I think I am missing the concept. I think the intercept is A1. Hence, Why do we not compare the levels of A1:B1 and A1(intercept)  or A2:B1 and A1(intercept)?

```
#nested model 
> mod<-aov(y~A+A:B)
> model.matrix(mod)
  (Intercept) A2 A1:B2 A2:B2 A1:B3 A2:B3 A1:B4 A2:B4
1           1  0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2           1  0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3           1  0     1     0     0     0     0     0
4           1  0     1     0     0     0     0     0
5           1  1     0     0     0     1     0     0
6           1  1     0     0     0     1     0     0
7           1  1     0     0     0     0     0     1
8           1  1     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: The intercept represents the first group (depending on the factor levels). In your example the first group would be A == A1 *and* B == B1. Thus, an interaction `A1:B1` is not needed in the model.

Comment: @Roland what about A2:B1? Why is A1:B2 included but not A2:B1?

Comment: Because that group can be determined by the intercept plus the A2 effect.

Comment: @Roland so you are saying that A2:B1 is pairwise multiplication of the intercept  and the A2 effect ,therefore, A2:B1 is already explained by columns intercept and A2 so R excludes the column A2:B1. A1:B2 however cannot be formed by pairwise multiplication of any of the first order columns ie intercept and A2, therefore, the column A1:B2 is included inside the model.

Comment: The mean of the group A1/B1 is predicted by the intercept; the mean of the group A2/B1 is predicted by the intercept plus the A2 effect; the mean of the group A2/B4 is predicted by the intercept plus the A2 effect + the A2:B4 effect. You can check this by using `predict` and comparing the result with manual calculations.

Comment: @Roland I understand what you mean. Just an additional question. Is there any relationship between the means of the levels with the estimated coefficients? For example, I know the intercept is expressed as the means of all the observations in the first group ie group A1 and B1. Can I find the A2 effect by considering means of the levels?

Comment: The model predicts the group means.

Comment: @Roland Thanks that makes sense. Do the coefficients of the dummy variables have some sort of meaning? For example, the intercept is the mean of the first group. Does A2 merely represent the effect on A1:B1 when the observation belongs to a particular group?

Comment: Yes, they have meaning. You should study contrasts, in particular treatment contrasts.